# Exchanging the internal letters of words

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, linq, scramble

How can you implement the "old" trick of scrambling the internal letters of words?

For those of you who don't know it [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typoglycemia) describes it well.

As mentioned in the comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6975437/256431) this has had some [research](http://www.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/people/matt.davis/cmabridge/) into the "research" originally mentioned in the earliest form of this meme.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this in "one" line of VB:

```
Dim outText = Regex.Replace(inText, _
        "\b([a-zA-z])([a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z])\b", _
        Function(g) (g.Groups(1).Value & String.Join("", _
            (g.Groups(2).Value.ToCharArray.OrderBy( _
                            Function(c) (Rnd(1))) _
                            )) & _
            g.Groups(3).Value))
```

A better solution would provide a 'more correct' `Function` for `OrderBy` that would return the same value for a particular character in a string, but in this case, simply setting the `Rnd` seed would do to get (somewhat) repeatable results.

(Note that setting the `Function` to be directly dependent upon the `c` provided means all internal characters are reordered according to some random ordering, so all internal repeated letters are always grouped together in the scrambled words.)

An example of the output:

> (Note that sttenig the `Fictunon` to be drcteily dpeednent uopn
>    the `c` previodd mnaes all inratnel cthcearras are roeerredd
>    aindorccg to smoe ronadm oidrreng, so all ietnnarl reteaepd
>    ltteers are awayls guorped tgtheoer in the srlmceabd wodrs.)

Comment: Nice. Is there an easy way to get the index of the character into the function? Just wondering because then you could create a deterministic function that wouldn't necessarily group together duplicate characters. I know you could do it by having an external counter that you increment but that is not a very pretty technique. :)

Comment: @Chris: Yes, especially if you expanded the outer `Function` to a standalone, or multi-line, function: the `Groups`, which are `Captures`, contain the `Index` of the match in the original string, so more could be done to provide a "proper" and/or repeatable `Function` for `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Mark Hurd is flawed. Even with the problem with duplicate letters corrected, the use of the sort algorithm does not yield a valid result.
// See http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/perfect-shuffle.txt

Here is my attempt, using recursion. Very simple and easy to understand, but performance could be improved. Obviously it does not use regex, vb.net or linq (see tags). I leave that to the reader.

```
Random _rng = new Random();

string Scramble(string text) {
  return String.Concat(text[0], Shuffle3(text.Substring(1, text.Length - 2)), text[text.Length - 1]);
}

string Shuffle3(string text) {
  return ShuffleStep(text, _rng.Next(text.Length));
}

string ShuffleStep(string text, int i) {
  return (text.Length == 1) ? text : text[i] + ShuffleStep(text.Remove(i, 1), _rng.Next(text.Length-1));
}
```

Comment: I have implemented an `.OrderRandomly` extension method using the correct shuffle you've pointed out, but as I've used VB.NET without `Yield` it isn't worth putting it up here.